# Run only the Linux kernel and user programs

Tags: linux, embedded, startup

is it possible to run only a Linux kernel on a system which will load my programs instead of an operating system?

I want to work with a Raspberry Pi with a Linux kernel. I am trying to create a server and client programs on Raspberry Pi and for this I need only a kernel which will work on network drivers.

I want raspberry pi to run only my programs when I switch it on. I don't want the rest of the operating system.

Answer (score 3):

When the Linux kernel starts, it runs the program `/sbin/init`. (That's after the [initrd](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/initrd.txt) or [initramfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt)) if any, and the location can be configured with the `init` [parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt). The [init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) program has a special role: it keeps running forever (there's a special rule that prevents it from being killed even with SIGKILL), it adopts [orphan processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process), and of course it's supposed to start (and monitor) other programs.

You can specify your own program as init. Then it's entirely up to you what you run.

However, you'll lose a lot if you do this. For example, you won't be able to reconfigure your device in any way (e.g. change the network configuration, or modify the bootloader settings) without physical access, unless you provide a program to do that. I recommend that you run at least a minimal set of tools:

- [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/), which is a suite of system tools including an init implementation, a shell and other command line tools. You'll probably want at least some of the BusyBox tools to set up the network at boot time anyway (`ifconfig`, `route`, …).
- [IPtables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables), the basic firewall configuration tool, which is not included in BusyBox.
- [Dropbear](http://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html), an SSH server, which will allow you to log into your device remotely.
- Possibly [other small tools](http://www.busybox.net/tinyutils.html), in praticular an [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) client (to set the clock) and [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html), a DNS cache.

All of these tools have a tiny footprint — they fit comfortably in about 10MB of RAM and 3MB of compressed storage, which is negligible for a Raspberry Pi. There's nothing to be gained on an RPi from reducing the system below that of a normal embedded Linux. Using a Linux kernel only to boot one program can be useful for very limited devices, but an RPi is at least two orders of magnitude above that.

The easiest way for you is to use one of the many [embedded Linux distributions](http://elinux.org/Embedded_Linux_Distributions). Alternatively, you can use a tool like [Buildroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buildroot) to build a custom system — this is useful for tiny systems, but a bit overkill for an RPi.